# Why compiler can't move unique_ptr from variadic arguments?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am creating a "job" that store unique pointers to basic "tasks"

```
    class JobBase
    {
    protected:

        template<typename... BaseOperations>
        JobBase(const std::wstring& operationDescription, BaseOperations&&... args)
            : m_operationDescription(operationDescription)
            , m_BaseOperations{std::move<BaseOperations>(args)...}
        {
        }

    private:

        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Task>> m_BaseOperations;
}
```

And create job with few tasks:

```
std::unique_ptr<Task> pTask = std::make_unique<Task>();
auto asyncCompOp2 = std::make_shared<Job>(L"AsyncOp", std::move(pTask));
```

But when I build my program I receive error:

```
Error   C2664   'std::unique_ptr<Task,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &&std::move<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>(std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &&) noexcept': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to '_Ty &&'
```

And I don't understant what is wrong. I created classic constructor, that accepts unique_ptr and emplaced passed value to vector and all working good.
Task class now doesn't have members, dtor, copy/move operators and ctors.
Please, help me undestand what I need to do

Full code sample

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Task
{
public:
    void Run() {}
};

class Job
{
public:
    template<typename... BaseOperations>
    Job(const std::wstring& name, BaseOperations&&... args)
        : m_Name(name)
        , m_BaseOperations{ std::forward<BaseOperations>(args)... }
    {
    }
private:
    std::wstring m_Name;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Task>> m_BaseOperations;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Task> pOp3 = std::make_unique<Task>();
    auto asyncCompOp2 = std::make_shared<Job>(L"AsyncOp", std::move(pOp3));
}
```

Comment: there's no `std::vector` constructor just taking elements right? There is one taking an initializer list of elements though, maybe try calling that one

Comment: @PeterT, yes, thank you, i found this issue. But for forward error - deleted function, for move - cannot convert Ty to Ty&&

Comment: Prefer to `std::forward` your received variadic arguments instead of `std::move`; the difference is subtle but important.

Comment: @AndyG Thank you, I tried forward - but "attemting to reference a deleted function" error occurs

Comment: @drem1lin that was just generic advice. We really can't help you until you provide a [mcve]

Comment: `initializer_list` basically doesn't support move semantics, it always copies. So there isn't really a way to list initialize an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`. It can be very annoying.

Comment: The error is complaining about `std::move`, right?  But the argument shown is not of type _Ty but a unique_pointer.  Strange.  Anyway, try writing it on one line directly without the variable that needs moving from:  `std::make_shared<Job>(L"AsyncOp", std::make_unique<Task>());`